# How to synchronize a cut-off git repo with another git repository in other remote server

Tags: git, github

I have two git repositories in two remote servers A and B and I want to transfer the master branch from A to master branch in B. But the problem is the git repo in A is very large with 6 years old and more than 20000 commits, and I do not want to transfer all of the commits to B.

I found a solution in the internet that with the command `--orphan <d-sha1>` I can cut off the content in A from a specific commit, and then from there I can push to origin B

```
git checkout --orphan cutoff <d-sha1>
git push origin_B master
```

But with this solution, when ever new commit is comming to B and I want to synchonize these two repos, I have to delete B and make again the same process which I do not think a good idea.

Does anyone have an idea what could be here an optimized solution for this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do I understand you correct: You are trying to syncronise two *different* Git Repositories?

Comment: yes they are two different repositories in two different git servers, but they will have the same project

Comment: So you are trying to mirror repo _A_ to repo _B_?